# get() in node.js app is not getting called when I try to hit localhost

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node.js. I have the below program called app.js running on my laptop

```
var express = require('express');
var engine = require('consolidate');

var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname);
app.engine('html', engine.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static('.'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Got request for index.html");
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(5000, '0.0.0.0');
```

and I have index.html in the same path as app.js. When I tried to hit localhost:5000 from browser or from postman, I am getting index.html as response. I thought app.get() will be called and the log "Got request for index.html" will be displayed. But that function is not getting called. I understood that .get() is called for routing.

I am not sure how browser / postman is getting index.html as response if get() in app.js is not getting hit. Can any one please help me to understand how postman is getting response even though app.get() is not getting called.

Comment: Did you try without setting the host? `0.0.0.0` isn't the same as `localhost`; `127.0.0.1` is `localhost` (in general). But `host` param shouldn't be necessary for local testing.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I tried without setting the host also like app.listen(5000).

Comment: I used it. Still not getting the log printed out.

Comment: The log is always going to get printed server side, as it's server side code. You wont see anything in the browser...

Comment: I am not checking on the browser. I am checking on the console on the terminal where I am running the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express middlewares are applied in order. `express.static` doesn't call the next middleware in the chain if it matches on a file - it just serves the file and ends the response. So because index.html is in your static files directory it means the app.get middleware is never called.

Generally you'd create a public folder for your static assets and a views folder for your HTML views.

something like:

```
const {join} = require('path');
app.set('views', join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.engine('html', engine.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'mustache');
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname,'/public')));
```

and make sure your index.html is in the views folder and your static assets are in the public folder

Comment: Thanks Michael. Our whole intention is to serve index.html as response. There won't be any other requests for this server. Can I remove everything and just leave app.get(), so app.get will be called every time.

Comment: If you don't have any static assets like images or scripts then you could do that. Just remove the express static middleware.

Comment: When mobile app hits our server, it sends some encrypted data as one of the headers for API. We need to some how access this header inside index.html.

Comment: Commenting out app.use(express.static('.')) is throwing error, when I am trying to access localhost:5000

Comment: Sorry. I solved the error and understood it clearly. Thanks a lot Michael.